Manga where people with superpowers get grades 1 for highest or 2, 3, 4
It's a manga where people have super powers and people get graded on abilities like 1 for really strong and 2, 3 or 4 (I think). Now the main character is a girl who is powerless and a level 0 which means she's the most attractive to anyone with powers, the stronger the powers the more attractive she is to them. I had this saved on my manga site but it was deleted. I've tried all manga sites, tvtropes, reddit and a few Ai.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

What sort of world/time period was the story set in?

It's set in modern times and our world. People with powers are hidden from society and they go to a special school for super powers.

I read this maybe 4 years ago. It's recent and in full color.

do you still have the link? it might be possible to find the name of it from the archive or google cache.
